# Kill process instead of panic on hung_task

Tags: linux, process-management, sysctl

There are [sysctl parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) for hung_task* that allow you to emit error messages or panic if a process is in the D state for some amount of time.

Is there anyway way to have the kernel kill the process rather than panic? I'd like the same detection mechanism (process in D state for too long) but I just want to kill the process rather than have the machine reboot.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way of waking up such a process is to make the awaited condition happen.

Historically, the "D" wait state means disk wait and this is considered a short and thus unbreakable wait.

If the condition, the process is awaiting is not a NFS filesystem that was not mounted with the `intr` option, this must be seen as a driver bug.